# Reset Safari in MacOs Big Sur

Tags: safari, performance, settings, bookmarks

My Safari browser freezes immediately upon launch, so I want to completely reset all settings.

(the problem is I accidentally bookmarked a Jupyter server in Favorites, and this freezes the client completely upon startup, because the server address does not exist anymore)

I tried deleting my bookmarks:

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

and other Safari plist files I could find:

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

But that does not completely remove the Favorites, it still visible after launch:
[image: frozen Safari]

How do I remove the Favorites? In what file are they stored?

I cannot do anything in the browser because it shows a spinning wheel, so I need to delete all settings from outside Safari.

**update**: Not sure what did it, but after a reboot and opening Safari while holding shift+option+command the favorites were reset, so now it works again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to reset all Safari settings from terminal :

First you quit Safari then :

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari*

rm -r ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari

rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
```

I think it's enough.

Edit.

You can try a boot in Safe Mode to clear the system caches.
Then you reboot in normal mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I removed those files and directories, but Safari still freezes. Those Favorites must be stored somewhere else